# different between python and ruby when parsing URL path, which is valid?

Tags: python, ruby, url, rfc3986

I have a URL string as:

```
url = "https://foo.bar.com/path/to/aaa.bbb/ccc.ddd;dc_trk_aid=486652617;tfua=;gdpr=;gdpr_consent=?&339286293"
```

when using Python

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url_obj = urlparse(url)
url_obj.path  # `path/to/aaa.bbb/ccc.ddd`
```

when using ruby

```rb
url_obj = URI.parse(url)

url_obj.path # `path/to/aaa.bbb/ccc.ddd;dc_trk_aid=486652617;tfua=;gdpr=;gdpr_consent=`
```

I guess python is consider `;` is not part of the url path, which one is 'correct'?

Comment: according to rfc it should be allowed ... maybe a bug with urlparse (but it does seem to be available in `url_obj.params`

Comment: @JoranBeasley AFAIK `;` was recommended (at least at some point in the past) as an alternative to `&` as a query parameter delimiter. That would only apply *after* a `?` though, but perhaps that's behind what Python is doing.

Comment: @muistooshort understood,  this example url I given is capture from browser,  and I have to parse and use it so I we have no choice but deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `urllib` is wrong. [RFC 3986 *Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax*, Section 3.3 *Path*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) explicitly gives this exact syntax as an example for a valid path [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is considered opaque by the generic syntax. URI producing applications often use the reserved characters allowed in a segment to delimit scheme-specific or dereference-handler-specific subcomponents. For example, **the semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are often used to delimit parameters and parameter values** applicable to that segment. The comma (",") reserved character is often used for similar purposes.  For example, **one URI producer might use a segment such as "name;v=1.1" to indicate a reference to version 1.1 of "name"**, whereas another might use a segment such as "name,1.1" to indicate the same. Parameter types may be defined by scheme-specific semantics, but in most cases the syntax of a parameter is specific to the implementation of the URI's dereferencing algorithm.

The *correct* interpretation of the example URI you posted is the following:

- *scheme* = `https`
- *authority* = `foo.bar.com`

  - *userinfo* = empty
  - *host* = `foo.bar.com`
  - *port* = empty, derived from the *scheme* to be `443`
- *path* = `/path/to/aaa.bbb/ccc.ddd;dc_trk_aid=486652617;tfua=;gdpr=;gdpr_consent=`, consisting of the following four *path segments*:

  1. `path`
  2. `to`
  3. `aaa.bbb`
  4. `ccc.ddd;dc_trk_aid=486652617;tfua=;gdpr=;gdpr_consent=`
- *query* = `&339286293`
- *fragment* = empty

Comment: Not really wrong. `urlparse` is being "helpful", by splitting parameters (per quoted RFC) of the last path segment into its own field. There is a function in `urllib` that does not do this, so I'd rather say `urlparse` is odd, than `urllib` as a package is wrong.

Comment: thanks for the detail,  at least for now I just follow the parse result form ruby's and ignore the py version

Answer (score 6):

`urlparse` takes the part of `path` after the first semicolon as `params`:

```
url_obj.path   # '/path/to/aaa.bbb/ccc.ddd'
url_obj.params # 'dc_trk_aid=486652617;tfua=;gdpr=;gdpr_consent='
```

To replicate Ruby's behaviour, use [`urlsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) instead:

> This is similar to `urlparse()`, but does not split the params from the URL. This should generally be used instead of `urlparse()` if the more recent URL syntax allowing parameters to be applied to each segment of the *path* portion of the URL (see RFC 2396) is wanted.

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

url_obj = urlsplit(url)
url_obj.path  # '/path/to/aaa.bbb/ccc.ddd;dc_trk_aid=486652617;tfua=;gdpr=;gdpr_consent='
```

Comment: thanks Amadan,  the issue for me is I am translating a python script to a ruby equivalent,  so I guess we found a 'bug' of the original python script and do the correct behavior in the ruby version. at least this help to fix that.